# How to send python logs to syslogs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am using [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) for generating logs on my python (2.7) project. I create one instance of logger class on each python file (`LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)` like this).

I want to send all the logs to syslog. Ways I have found using [SysLogHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler) needs to specify the address (`/dev/log`, `/var/run/syslog` etc.)  of syslogs which can be different on different platforms.

Is there any generic way to do it (send the logs to syslog)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler

Comment: Can you specify if you are doing Python 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini See the edited question :)

Answer (score 1):

As you found, you configure logging to use the SysLogHandler.  As you also noted, the "address" will be different on different systems and configurations.  You will need to make that a configurable part of your application.

If you are configuring the logging programmatically, you could implement some heuristics to search for the various UNIX domain socket paths you expect to find.

Note the syslog can use UDP or TCP sockets to log to a remote syslog server instead of using a UNIX domain socket on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, logging

class streamToLogger(object):

    def __init__(self, logger, log_level = logging.INFO):

        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.linebuf = ''

    def write(self, buf):

        for line in buf.rstrip().splitlines():

            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())


logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',
    filename = os.path.join('/var/log', 'logfile.log'),
    filemode = 'a'
)

sys.stdout = streamToLogger(logging.getLogger('STDOUT'), logging.INFO)
sys.stderr = streamToLogger(logging.getLogger('STDERR'), logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Writing directly to a file in `/var/log` does not constitute using syslog.